# mapping Inheritance and native query in doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have next structure :

```
                   +------+
                   |      |
                   |  A1  |                    Class A1
                   |      |
                   +--+---+                    Class A2 - child
                      ^                        Class A3 - child
                      |
                      |                        A2->B1 (Class B1)
             +--------+--------+               A3->B2 (Class B2)
             |                 |
             |                 |
+-----+   +--+---+          +--+--+   +-----+
|     |   |      |          |     |   |     |
| B1  +---+  A2  |          | A3  +---+ B2  |
|     |   |      |          |     |   |     |
+-----+   +------+          +-----+   +-----+
```

It's single table inheritance so A1,A2,A3 are in single DB table (a1). I need to creative Native Query and mapping that will load all entities from single table with all associated entities (B1, B2) at once. Query looks like this :

```
SELECT a1.*, b1.id AS b1_id,...,b2.id AS b2_ID... 
   FROM a1
   LEFT JOIN b1 ON (a1.b1 = b1.id)
   LEFT JOIN b2 ON (a1.b2 = b2.id)
```

I have try something like this :

```
$mapping = new ResultSetMapping();
$mapping->addEntityResult(A1::class, 'a');
$mapping->addFieldResult('a', 'id', 'id');
...
$mapping->addMetaResult('a', 'a_type', 'a_type');
$mapping->setDiscriminatorColumn('a', 'a_type');
```

but how to map associated entities (B1,B2) ? I have try `addJoinedEntityResult` but it's require to use child class instead of base class. Is it possible to make such mapping? I didn't find any example of such case on [DOCTRINE NATIVE QUERY](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#examples)